# RTABMAP estimate normals with external odometry

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use external odometry to estimate normals with RTABMAP?
Will the normals then be estimated based on the odom when the points where captured?
I know icp_odometry have some parameters for normal estimation, but I have not found any examples using them.

My goal is to user Intel RealSense D435 and T265 cameras to scan a box from five sides and use the normals to decide tcp orientation for a robot so that its tool is perpendicular to the surface.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374076/rtabmap-estimate-normals-with-external-odometry/) by [MRRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39980/mrrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2021-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normals are inverted if needed based on the current point of view.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2021-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MRRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39980/mrrobot/) on 2021-03-22**:
Do I understand it correct that RTABMAP will orient all normals according to current pov and not store the pov from when the point was captured?
If I were to scan one side of a box and then scan the opposite side, all surface normals would have the same direction and be oriented according to the last side, and not in opposite directions?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2021-03-22**:
`/rtabmap/cloud_map` doesn't have normals published. When doing File->Export Clouds, normals are adjusted depending on each camera point of view. See [adjustNormalsToViewPoints()](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/blob/cad184e82bef25b90967ab88ebab5e99a7ce26bf/corelib/src/util3d_surface.cpp#L3481-L3525). For each point, we search the camera looking at it, then flip the normal is needed.

**Comment by [MRRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39980/mrrobot/) on 2021-03-22**:
I see. Thank you for the clarification!